# ScrollEventArgs constructor with float as argument

Tags: c#, event-handling

`public ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType type, int Value)`

Accepts only integer as argument. But I need to send float, calculated dynamically.If i am rounding 7.5 to 7 or 8 and scrolling it for 4 times makes either 28 or 32. Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).